# Issue applying multiple classes

Tags: jquery, css, class

I have some jQuery styled to fade in my logo and nav. This works fine with my logo, however when I apply my fade class to my navigation it only works if its the only class applied. Any suggestions on how to solve this to where I can apply the multiple classes and have the fade work?

Here is the HTML portion

```
    <div id="header" class="clearfix shadow">
        <div class="container_12">
            **<div class="fade" id="logo">**
                <?php cudazi_get_logo(); // in functions.php ?>
            </div><!--//logo-->
            **<div class="fade grid_8 menu-container">**
                <ul class="main-menu clearfix"><?php
                    $arr_pages_menu = get_pages(
                        array(
                            'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
                            'sort_order' => 'ASC',
                            'exclude' => array(
                                $custom_settings["page_on_front"]
                            )
                        )
                    );
```

Here is the CSS

```
    .fade { 
display:none;
    }
```

Here is the jQuery

```
    $(window).load(function() {
    $(".fade").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i * 800).fadeIn(8000);
    });
    });

 });
```

Comment: Showing your PHP is not helpful. Show your HTML.

Comment: Its built through wordpress, its dynamic.I actually figured it out. I applied display:none; to my grid_8 class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it always visible?  If so, I'm guessing that one of the other classes has a display set in its class that's overriding the .fade display:none.  try marking the fade's display as !important:

.fade {
    display:none !important;
}

or switching the order:

"grid_8 menu-container fade"